# Java Binder FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION in the flutter app

Tags: android, ios, flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy, wifi

I am sending a file through peer to peer service using Bluetooth and Wi-Fi (P2P_STAR) with the help of Nearby Service queue from flutter nearby connections library for its support for both systems android and ios (not nearby connections library)
The file is expected to be sent at a high speed thanks to the realization of this connection
But it is as follows
First I convert the image file to an array of bits and then I convert this array to Base64
As an experience of sending the image and receiving it by the other device

problems:

1- When you send an image file, for example, with a size of 50 kilobytes at most, the image will be sent successfully

2 When the image file size exceeds 256 KB, a message is displayed that the image file is being sent, and after a few minutes, the connection between the two parties is cut off

3- When the image file exceeds 1 megabyte, it gives the following error
Java Binder FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION

This picture shows the error

[image: This picture shows the error]

Note: I work `compileSdkVersion 31` and `minSdkVersion 21`.